# how do I exclude a go library from compilation on linux but not Mac/windows?

Tags: go, compilation, conditional-compilation

I use

```golang
import "github.com/dontpanic92/wxGo/wx"
```

in a program that can run with or without a GUI.

i.e. you might run it like:

```
./program --gui true
```

or

```
./program --gui false
```

When running on Linux with GUI false I'd like to avoid having to compile all of `wxGo/wx`.

How can I check in the same code to git so that it will compile on Mac or Linux just fine.

i.e. right now when I compile on Linux I have to comment out any reference to `wxGo/wx`

Comment: Use filenames of the form "whatever_linux.go" or "whatever_darwin.go" (or whatever_windows.go" or build tags.

Comment: For reference: [Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude specific Go files from building on certain operating system, architectures, Go versions or if certain tags are specified during compilation, these are your options:

1. If you want a file to only build on Linux, append `_linux` to the file name, e.g. `gui_linux.go`. It is also possible to specify an architecture, or both, e.g. `gui_windows_amd64.go`.
2. Add a `//+build ...` comment at the top of your Go file, e.g. `// +build linux,386`.

See https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints for details.

Comment: can I use the same main.go file? Like in main.go it imports the Gui library and makes one call to it if Gui flag is on. So on linux I keep commenting out those two lines in main. The import and the call. With your solution, can I still use just 1 main.go file?

Comment: No, you would have to use a `main_linux.go` and one `main_darwin.go` where your OS-specific code resides. They could be as easy as just having your bool variablel declared in each one, once true and once false. Then you can still have the `main.go` with all the main logic.